# Checking the existence of a named folder prior to creating it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Im trying to insert a specific file in Google Drive to a folder. I also want to check if there is a folder with name `'testFolder'`: if Yes, then insert file to that already existing folder, else create one named `'testFolder'`.

Here is what I have come up with so far, but it always creates a new folder named `'testFolder'` (so users have like 10 folders named `'testFolder'` now - it doesn't reuse the first folder).

```
var copyId = /* the id of the file to copy */;
function InsertFileToFolder() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);      
  var folder;
  if (folderExists() == true){                        
    folder = DriveApp.getFolder("testFolder"); //<-- No such thing in GAS i think?
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("testFolder");
  }
  folder.addFile(file);
}

//Check whether folder exists or not
function folderExists() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var flag = false;  
  for(var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++){
    if(folders[i].getName() == 'testFolder'){
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: What does the `folderExists())' function return? Is it true and you still end up with a new folder in the wrong place. or does it return false? Not finding the folder that it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `length` property of `folders`.  You need to use `hasNext()`.

[Google Documentation - Folder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)

```
// Log the name of every folder in the user's Drive.
var folder,folders;

folders = DriveApp.getFolders();

while (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
}
```

This code returns the folder ID if the folder being looked for is found:

```
function InsertFileToFolder() {
  var file,folder,
      folderIdOrFalse;
  file = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId);      

  folderIdOrFalse = folderExists();

  if (folderIdOrFalse !== false) {                        
    folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIdOrFalse);
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder("testFolder");
  }

  folder.addFile(file);
};

function folderExists() { //Check whether folder exists or not

  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var theReturn = false,
      i=0,
      folderName = "",
      folder;  

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    folderName = folder.getName();

    if (folderName === 'testFolder') {
      theReturn = folder.getId();
      break;
    };
  };

  return theReturn;
};
```

Comment: Thank You Sandy, spot on and of course, thanks for pointing me to the right direction, also your example worked perfect, didn't event have to change anything ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed its scripting. I know this is an old post but this is the best current answer I could come up with:

```
function getFolder(parent_folder,folder_name){
  var folders = parent_folder.getFolders();     
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if(folder_name == folder.getName()) {         
      return folder;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

var parent_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(//id\\);
var folderName = getFolders(parent_folder,name);
if (folderName === false){
  folderName =  outputfolderId.createFolder(name);
}
```

As found in this answer: [How to create a folder if it doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118809/create-a-folder-if-doesn%C2%B4t-exist/38024062#38024062)