# Upload files multiple times from Google Form to specific folder based on form entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to upload files from a Google Form to specific folder based on the form response.
Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531195/google-form-upload-files-to-specific-new-folder-based-on-the-value-submitted),

However, the issue is when the same user uploads multiple times, any file uploads after the first time would automatically send the file back to the original root folder.

What I would like is to allow the same user to upload multiple times and send the files uploaded by the same user to his already created subfolder (his name).

How do I do that?

[Edited with code i used]
Apologies.
I copied the code from this website, https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226, it worked but it recreates a subfolder with the file id as it’s name everytime.

[Additional Edits and Info]
I would like to clarify what I mean by multiple times.
It would mean the person will submit the form response multiple times, but with only 1 file upload at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same user uploads multiple times"? Does the form includes multiple upload file questions or the user is submitting multiple form responses ? Also, please show what you tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/56952300/1595451

Comment: If possible, kindly include a snippet of your code.

Comment: @Rubén Sorry it wasn’t stated clearly, what I meant is the user is submitting the form response multiple times, with only a single file upload each time. 

I would like the person to select his NAME, from the first question drop down list, and question 2 is the file upload button.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, your goals are:

- Create a folder using form answer (Name)
- Check if the folder exists by using the folder name.

  - If yes, move the attached files to the existing folder
  - If not, create new folder and move the attached files.

Here I copied the code you've provided and added Allan Wells` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331706) to check whether the folder exists or not.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "Parent folder ID here";

const initialize = () => {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter(
        (itemResponse) =>
          itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
      )
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      //get the first response (which is Name) and use it as subfolder name
      const subfolderName = response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
      //check if the subfolder name already exists
      var folderId = folderExists(subfolderName);
      var subfolder;
      
      if(folderId){ //if subfolder name already exists, use the folder ID to get the folder object
        subfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      }else{ //create new folder
        const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
        subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      }
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};


function folderExists(fname) { //Check whether folder exists or not
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID).getFolders();
  var theReturn = false,
      i=0,
      folderName = "",
      folder;  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    folderName = folder.getName();
    if (folderName.toLowerCase() == fname.toLowerCase()) {
      theReturn = folder.getId();
      break;
    };
  };
  return theReturn;
};
```

**Sample Form:**

[image]

**Sample Output:**

*Here I submitted multiple forms for "Test Name"*

[image]

### Reference:

- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

Comment: Hey! This works great!!! 
Thank you so much! 

Another thing, I tried playing around with capitalisation, is there anyway we can make it so that it is not case sensitive?

Like for example, “John” or “john” submits, but the files should be uploaded to 1 folder?