# Create subfolder in a folder in Google Drive through Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a subfolder name "2017" in a folder "Reports" in Google drive through Google Apps Script. Before creating subfolder required to justify that subfolder exist or not. I made code just like below.... it works.
is there any easy way to code?

```
var reportFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName("Reports");
if(reportFolder.hasNext()){
    var reportFolderExist = reportFolder.next();
    var yearFolders = reportFolderExist.getFoldersByName("2017");
    if(yearFolders.hasNext()){
        var yearFolderExist = yearFolders.next().getName();
        return 'Yes, There is 2017 folder.' ;
    } else {
        reportFolderExist.createFolder("2017");
        return 'There was no 2017 folder. But created' ;
    }
} else {
    return 'No "Reports" folder exist';
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118809/how-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-exist/38024062#38024062). I guess there's no other easy way...

Comment: Since the DriveApp uses iterators instead of arrays I think what you have is pretty reasonable.

Comment: that's simplenough, what part of the script is unclear?

Comment: thanks @JuanDiegoAntezana actually I thought these code can be convert into one line code or more less than my. any way, can you suggest me how i can create a Spreadsheet file named "02 February" inside "2017" subfolder. Obviously it is required to justify that the named file exist or not.

Comment: @MohiUddin - I'm guessing you may already have figured this out but on the off chance you're still looking, do you intend to create a sub-folder for every month or are you asking specifically only for **02 February**? I'm guessing you may also want **01 January**, **03 March**, **04 April** & so on..